# Peculiar issue: Simple Rspec spec passes on Linux but not on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ubuntu, rspec

I have the following spec:

```
it 'should find and associate thumbnail and video for article with an episode with the first alpha-numerically matching files it finds' do

  @article = FactoryGirl.create(:pending_assets_article, id: 1)
  @episode1 = FactoryGirl.create(:episode, topic_id: @topic.id, article_id: @article.id, position: 1)
  @article.video.should be_nil
  @article.thumbnail.image.should be_blank
  @article.state.should == 'pending assets'

  run_rake_task

  Delayed::Job.count.should == 2
...
end
```

The peculiar thing is this spec passes just fine in Ubuntu, but in Mac OS X Lion it fails, saying something like `expected 2, got 0`.

What gives??

I'd be happy to add more surrounding code to give more context.

Comment: Do you have rmagick setup on your mac?

Comment: Yes, `rmagick` is included in the Gemfile and installed as part of `bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking the rake task?  If you're shelling out to another process, you may be hitting transaction boundaries in your datastore.

You should ideally source/execute the rake task within your rspec context:

```
require 'rake'
Rake::Task[name].invoke
```

For example, if you're running postgres as the backend to your DelayedJob queue and using transactional rollbacks of data in rspec, you have test data in one transaction for the test setup, shell out to the rake task, which changes data outside the transaction, return to the test and original transaction, and can't "see" the data.

Additionally, it may be simpler to verify that your code is enqueuing the job in DelayedJob using a Mock and an expectation than querying the size of the queue in the data store.